# asp to php translator

Tags: php, asp-classic

I am looking for some asp to php translator.

I tried http://www.design215.com/toolbox/translator/ it is totally buggy.

please suggest me good think.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the translator as a tool to learn one of ASP or PHP, or do you want to use the translated code? If the latter, the only reliable translator will be human.

Answer (score 2):

There is no commercially available or open source product that will turn classic ASP pages into PHP.

I've heard of companies rolling their own ASP to PHP compiler internally, but it always relies on keeping yourself to a particular subset of each language and/or external features (PHP Extensions, ASP Components, etc.)

You will not find what you're looking for.

Comment: yea nothing great found on the web. Let see!

Answer (score 0):

This is something else that I found:

```
http://asp2php.naken.cc/docs.php
```

Haven't tried it out. But translation is probably not a very robust solution.

Comment: download and tried, not working :(

Comment: I have to agree with what Alan said above. If you're looking for a 1-to-1 translation, you're not likely to find it. The best solution is to translate it by hand.